# Ubuntu 16.04 Wifi networks grayed out - Dell Latitude E5470

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, dell

I have seen many posts about Wifi problems in various versions of Ubuntu but non of the responses seem to be applicable to me.

This is the output of `rfkill list`:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

And this is the output of `sudo lshw -C network`:

```
  *-network DISABLED      
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlp1s0
       version: 32
       serial: 40:49:0f:06:1d:1f
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.4.0-21-generic firmware=WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:130 memory:e1000000-e11fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection I219-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 21
       serial: 28:f1:0e:0f:2e:23
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.13-3 ip=192.168.1.110 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:127 memory:e1300000-e131ffff
```

I see these two grayed out in my network menu (top right):
"WiFi Networks"
"device not ready"

I have spent two weeks trying to fix this problem on 3 different ubuntu releases (14.10, 15.10, and now 16.04) on this laptop which is now a dual boot of Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04.
Any help would be much appreciated.

output of `dmesg | grep ath`:

```
[    8.982622] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    8.983651] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: pci irq msi-x interrupts 8 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[    9.260939] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:01:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    9.269044] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin failed with error -2
[    9.269048] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin': -2
[    9.368509] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin failed with error -2
[   11.640870] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 (0x05030000, 0x00340aff sub 1028:0310) fw WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1 fwapi 4 bdapi 1 htt-ver 3.26 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1 features wowlan,ignore-otp,no-4addr-pad
[   11.640873] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[   14.637936] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[   14.705845] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x6c
[   14.705848] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[   14.705850] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[   14.705850] ath: Regpair used: 0x6c
[   14.844845] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0 wlp1s0: renamed from wlan0
[   26.098537] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[   32.098781] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[   37.930829] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[   43.931047] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[   49.243463] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[   55.243906] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[   71.260298] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[   77.260556] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[   82.572856] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[   88.573096] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[  104.253467] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to set rx-chainmask: -11, req 0x3
[  107.253817] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to set arp ac override parameter: -11
[  113.253791] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[  118.566289] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to set tx-chainmask: -11, req 0x3
[  121.566223] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to set arp ac override parameter: -11
[  127.566616] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[  139.263049] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[  145.263314] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[  150.575255] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to set rx-chainmask: -11, req 0x3
[  153.575438] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to set arp ac override parameter: -11
```

Comment: Your wireless probably needs firmware. Please edit your question to add the result of: `dmesg | grep ath` Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: Thanks a lot chili555 for your comment. I added the output. I would appreciate any further feedback.

Comment: Was this before or after trying chili555's answer?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you install the required firmware for your device. With a working internet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.158_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware*.deb
sudo modprobe -r ath10k_pci && sudo modprobe ath10k_pci
```

Also, it appears that the driver wants but cannot find a region code. I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit.

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Reboot and let us know if it is working as expected.

Comment: Thanks a lot chili555. There seems to be a problem with my work place Ethernet connection that blocks certain repos. I would have to try this with another Ethernet and see if I can solve this. So far, nothing has changed following your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. As you and others point out, the Dell wireless card didn't have an Ubuntu driver. I purchased an external USB wireless card and after a few months Dell added the driver for the card and the problem automatically was fixed after one of the automatic system updates.

Comment: This worked for me! I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 on Dell Latitude E5470. I upgraded from linux firmware version 1.158 to 1.167. After modprobe, wifi started working without a restart.

Answer (score 0):

1.Download from  https://github.com/FireWalkerX/ath10k-firmware/blob/7e56cbb94182a2fdab110cf5bfeded8fd1d44d30/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin?raw=true, then rename to board.bin.

2.Download from  https://github.com/FireWalkerX/ath10k-firmware/blob/7e56cbb94182a2fdab110cf5bfeded8fd1d44d30/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-4.bin_WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1?raw=true, and then rename to firmware-4.bin

3.Put all above to /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/

4.reboot your machine

finally,my solution come from : `https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1604345#p1604345`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. As you and others point out, the Dell wireless card didn't have an Ubuntu driver. I purchased an external USB wireless card and after a few months Dell added the driver for the card and the problem automatically was fixed after one of the automatic system updates.